# Both “INSERT IGNORE” and “… ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE” what happens?

Tags: mysql, sql, etl, talend

What will mysql do with both [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) and [`… ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) ?

This is not a question about their [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/548541/516748). I ask because Talend ETL does this behind the UI and I'm worried it will have side effects especially if I don't want to update and do something like this:

```
String insertIgnore_tMysqlOutput_10 = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `"
+ "Employees"
+ "` (`Name`,`JobTitle`) VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Name` = ?";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IGNORE` just acts as a kind of error-suppressor, making fatal errors act as warnings instead.

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` doesn't trigger an error, so `INGORE` has no effect on it.

Therefore, `IGNORE` has no effect on duplicate keys when `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is used as well. *However*, if a different error were to occur then `IGNORE` would indeed have an effect.

Comment: Hmm I think it is an error on the part of Talend ETL to use ignore

Comment: One example: inserting NULL into a NOT NULL will insert the column type default and silently continue